# time complexity of three codes where variables depend on each other

Tags: c++11

```
1) i=s=1;
while(s<=n)
{
   i++;
   s=s+i;
}            

2) for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
     for(int j=1;j<=n;j+=i)
      cout<<"*";

3)   j=1;
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
          for(j=j*i;j<=n;j=j+i)
                cout<<"*";
```

can someone explain me the time complexity of these three codes?
   I know the answers but I can't understand how it came

Comment: Please describe as much as you understand about the timing behaviour and about deriving the time complexity from it. A complete explanation of all  aspects is otherwise too broad. You might also want to read the [tour], especially [ask]. I can imagine why you do not want to show the known answer, but it might be more inviting to answerers if you did.

Answer (score 0):

1) To figure this out, we need to figure out how large `s` is on the `x`'th iteration of the loop. Then we'll know how many iterations occur until the condition `s > n` is reached.

On the `x`'th iteration, the variable `i` has value `x + 1`
And the variable `s` has value equal to the sum of `i` for all previous values. So, on that iteration, `s` has value equal to

```
sum_{y = 1 .. x} (y+1) = O(x^2)
```

This means that we have `s = n` on the `x = O(\sqrt{n})` iteration. So that's the running time of the loop.

If you aren't sure about why the sum is `O(x^2)`, I gave an answer to another question like this once [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315977/what-is-big-o-of-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrtn/315981#315981) and the same technique applies. In this particular case you could also use an identity

```
sum_{y = 1 .. x} y = y choose 2 = (y+1)(y) / 2
```

This identity can be easily proved by induction on `y`.

2) Try to analyze how long the inner loop runs, as a function of `i` and `n`. Since we start at one, end at `n`, and count up by `i`, it runs `n/i` times. So the total time for the outer loop is

```
sum_{i = 1 .. n} n/i = n * sum_{i = 1 .. n} 1 / i = O(n log n)
```

The series `sum_{i = 1 .. n} 1 / i` is called the harmonic series. It is well-known that it converges to `O(log n)`. I can't enclose here a simple proof. It can be proved using calculus though. This is a series you just have to know. If you want to see a simple proof, you can look on on wikipedia at the "comparison test". The proof there only shows the series is >= log n, but the same technique can be used to show it is `<= O(log n)` also.

3.) This looks like kind of a trick question. The inner loop is going to run once, but once it exits with `j = n + 1`, we can never reenter this loop, because no later line that runs will make `j <= n` again. We will run `j = j * i` many times, where `i` is a positive number. So `j` is going to end up at least as large as `n!`. For any significant value of `n`, this is going to cause an overflow. Ignoring that possibility, the code is going to perform `O(n)` operations in total.